# How to dynamically change linear inequality constraints in MATLAB for genetic algorithm

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I am conducting an optimization problem using genetic algorithm in MATLAB. The general structure for executing ga is as shown below:

```
[xbest, fbest, exitflag] = ga(ObjectiveFunction, TotalVariables, Aineq, bineq, Aeq, beq, lb, ub, nonlinconstfn, [1:1:TotalVariables], opts)
```

`Aineq`, `Bineq`, `Aeq` and `beq` matrices are pre-defined before passing them as arguments to the ga function. However, now I need to change the `Aineq` and `bineq` corresponding to each value of `x` (where `x` is one of the chromosomes in that generation being evaluated in the Objective Function) in the calculation. In other words I need to pass an argument to `Aineq` and `bineq` to change a few values in the matrices. Is there any how to do this in MATLAB?

Comment: Should I change that to Aineq and bineq to non linear constraint function as by definition it is changing in a nonlinear manner in each iteration..?

Comment: Yes, you should be using non-linear constraints.

Comment: But the non-linear constraint is getting violated as mentioned by MATLAB at the end of the run. I have tried to check this each time in the nonlinear constraint function and passing a global penalty value from nonlinear constraint function to objective function in case it is violated.. Is this an efficient technique?

If violation_check == 0
 f = obj fn;
   else
 f = obj fn + penalty value
end

Comment: The non-linear constraint function shouldn't be checking if the constraint is violated - that is the job of the solver.  The constraint function should just return the value of the constraint.

Comment: So won't GA solver take care of this violation like it does with linear constraints? Right now I am manually increasing the cost function value by adding a linear penalty value term. Is this the best way for a work around this violation?

Comment: `best` is a very subjective word.  However, in general, you should not be adding your own penalty term if a constraint is violated.  That is the job of the solver.  You should simply be telling the solver what the constraint is.  If the constraint is violated then the solver will determine that its last guess (i.e. the one with led to a constraint being violated) is a bad one.

Comment: But in ga hat is not happening. After the couple of runs it stalls and says the best result obtained has violated some of the constraints - specifically the nonlinear constraints. However, with addition of penalty value in the cost function it seems to be working well